# reduce image size in image view in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I need to  reduce image size in iphone.

I found sending programmatically email in google,But did n't found clear info regarding reduce size of image view.

Can any one pls post some sample code.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: I have attached the code.. check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
UIImage* newImage = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newFrame); // this will crop    
    [sourceImage drawInRect:newFrame];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This will draw the image in the frame you specified. Now if you want to maintain the aspect ratio also you can have look at [Maintain the aspect ratio of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558461/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image/1559674#1559674)

As I saw that you are using image view, so don't use first part of code I mentioned. Now you have to do only:

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Comment: hi,im new in iphone.now im developing button image view in iphone.

Comment: images are displaying large size.can u plz send me code for how to resize the images in iphone.

Comment: @user549767 First of all u should resize the image accordingly and then set as the background image of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean scaling a view that an image is contained within, or do you mean you want to resample image data to make an image with a smaller file size?

First couple of results in google bring up this... [Resize Image](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html)

Comment: hi,can u plz send code for how to resize the button image in iphone

Answer (score 0):

Instead take UIButton and set the image as its backgroundImage property... It will automatically resize the image to the size of the button.

```
-(UIImage*)createThumbNailImage:(UIImage*)myThumbNail:(float)width:(float)height
{

// begin an image context that will essentially "hold" our new image

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width,height));

// now redraw our image in a smaller rectangle.
[myThumbNail drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];


// make a "copy" of the image from the current context
UIImage *newImage    = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



return [newImage autorelease];

}
```

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: im display images in imageview

Comment: okay then convert the image to the size you want to display it in. I have attached the code for creating thumbnail in my code.... :)