# Calculate image size based on Screen size in android

Tags: android, dynamic, image-processing

I am trying to calculate image height & width based on screen size.. I am getting 5'x 7' dimension image from back end , in order to convert pixels multiplying by 72 I have 360 X 504 dimension image. For 360 X 504 , my dynamic transparent rectangular area will appear at (1.223') x (1.179') i.e, 88.05 x 84.88. Now for screen size 320 x 480 I want to calculate my dynamic rectangular area's height & width. For this I use following calculation :

For height :

new height = (84.88/504)*480  =  80.83

where 84.88 - height of rectangular image , 504 - height of screen size , 480 - height of new screen size.

Same way for Width :

new width= (88.05/360)*320 = 78.26

Is this the way to calculate image size when Screen size increases or decreases? I need to place my dynamic image exactly over that Rectangular area (Brownish area) of Main Background image.

In short, I will get image **x,y position & height,width for 360X504**.. Now i need to calculate **x,y & height,width for 320x480**

[image]

Comment: You want to resize while maintaining the aspect ratio, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558461/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image

Comment: In case of Android we need to focus on Density factor. My guess is that problem is due to not considering Density and all.. Will this link be really useful to me? @gordy

Comment: @Venky : What are you trying to do that Android doesn't automatically do for different screen sizes and densities? I don't fully understand your question. By the way, 5'x7' is 5 feet x 7 feet, if you mean inches then it should be 5"x7".

Comment: I think I might be missing something.  Why are you bothering with actual size at all?  Why can't you just use pixels?  If I was solving this problem, I would create a custom view with the background image and a setImage() method to add the image you download.  In omMeasure(), get the size of the view in pixels and calculate the top and left of the image to place as percetanges of the view size.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Squonk You are right it's 5"..

Answer (score 2):

Why not pre-config them inside of your /drawables/ldpi ?

That way, when you inflate the button where you want, it would happen automatically.

You could also use:

API3+

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

API1+ (though now deprecated in newer APIs)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

To grab the display size and since you now know the Display Information, you can pick which /drawable element you want to inflate for by the name ( small.jpg , smaller.jpg ) with a small case/switch statement to handle odd screen sizes within that class of screen. This would have it work all the time and auto-size correctly.

This will take some headache out of it since the system already knows the dpi and the screen class ("large", "x-large", etc.), the system did the hard work for you!

Comment: The OP is downloading images from a server so using the different density folders for `/res/drawables` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you can pre-define the position in the layout, then you can probably crate different layout as per configuration

- ldpi
- mdpi
- etc

And set the `scaleType` property of the `ImageView`.

And later whenever you get image from the server, just set it to the View and it will automatically manage the scaling inclusive of the device dpi.

Comment: Thing is that images are populating dynamically.. I will get image x,y position & height,width for 360X504.. Now i need to calculate x,y & height,width for 320x480